# Expected OpenGL performance

Tags: opengl, performance

I'm benchmarking some simple code for drawing using OpenGL.

In the following code, the number of indices being drawn is 4,644 (or 1,548 triangles per frame = @60fps 92,880 Triangles per second).

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);                        
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glOrtho(0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 0, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         
glLoadIdentity();                                   
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(venomGLAttribute), ,drawingTexturedList.attrib[0].color);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_SHORT, sizeof(venomGLAttribute), &drawingTexturedList.attrib[0].pos[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(venomGLAttribute), &drawingTexturedList.attrib[0].UV[0]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, drawingTexturedList[cnt].currentIndice /*4644*/, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, drawingTexturedList[cnt].Indices);
```

This takes 100% of one of my CPU's. If I take out the call to glDrawElements but still perform all the other steps (geometry preperation, gl*Pointer setup) I see my CPU stay at ~3%.

Is this expected behaviour? The machine I'm running on has a GeForce 8800GTX and a Dual Core @ 2.66Ghz.

Using fps as a measurement (which isn't perfect I realise) and using gDEBugger to confirm my findings, rendering 27,904 triangles a frame in a single call to glDrawElements brings my frame rate down to ~35fps (or 977,640 triangles a second).

Is there a better way to pack my data than I'm doing or perhaps a better way to send the data than glDrawElements? I don't think using a VBO will help as the data being sent changes every frame.

Any idea's would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's somewhat to be expected (although your throughput is really low).

You're using about the worst method of drawing with vertex arrays: drawing indexed with client-side vertex data requires the GL implementation to:

- parse all the indices to find the min/max on each draw
- transfer all the vertex data from min to max on each draw.

Note that if you remove the draw, the GL will not do any of it, and it *will* be real fast.

if you don't want to use VBOs (they still help in that the GL can figure out easier how much to transfer), you can use [glDrawRangeElements](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawRangeElements.xml), which specifies the range of indices that the GL will transfer (ie the first of the 2 bullets).

Also, are the indices changing each frame too ? If they don't, you can store them in an index buffer. (but be careful: at that point, if you don't use glDrawRangeElements, the GL usually has to bring the index buffer back from the device, find min/max, and transfer vertex data. That's even worse than your current state)

Comment: Moving over to glDrawRangeElements didn't seem to make a difference. However moving to VBO's did actually speed it up considerably even though the data is being changed every frame. I'm seeing a throughput of about 15 million triangles / second now and a much lower CPU cost. Cheers!

Comment: @Olly: good to know you solved it. Whether the GL implements the optimizations I talked about really depends on each implementation you use, sadly.

Comment: I currently changed my implementation (using VBOs) from using glDrawElements, with a specified range, and client-side indices to using an ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER (an "index buffer"), and still drawing with glDrawElements (not RangeElements), and the performance just dropped! My draw calls went from taking 9 ms to 34 ms for the same mesh. Is that expected? I expected the opposite.

Comment: Now I even tried implementing using glDrawRangeElements with proper min/max and it still takes 34 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply reducing the size of the array, and seeing if it makes a difference? I have a feeling you are getting a false positive; by taking out the ONLY draw call, I think you are affecting OpenGL more significantly and I'm pretty sure if you replace it with an easier call you'll still see 100% CPU.

If that is the case, then you need to make sure you are sleeping in each iteration of the game loop, or enable vsync. If you don't sleep and just have a tight draw loop then you will naturally take up 100% of one CPU, but if you just add a sleep(0) call it should reduce to ~0% CPU.

Or I could be totally wrong; if that's the case, I apologize in advance.

Comment: I have VSync enabled. Plus I'm seeing the higher CPU when the draw call is in. If I take the draw call out I idle at ~3%. In fact if I do everything apart from the call to glDrawElements, it is steady at 3%. With the one call in, 100% on one CPU.